# Codename one-purchased certificate, but can't continue

Tags: codenameone

I have developped a Codename one App. It runs normally in Android. I am trying to make it run in Iphone as well.

1) I have purchased a developer apple account, paying the 100$.
2) I have generated a .cert file in windows, using instructions.
https://knowledge.digicert.com/solution/SO27347.html
3) I used ios signing to use the certificate there.

However, the one issue is "choose a device" from IOS certificate wizard, is empty. Check image.
Whenever i make an IOS build, it says build successful, but displays an error accepting the certificate.
What am i missing? What should i do?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the menu button on the top right click add device and add the UDID's for the devices you own. On these devices you will be able to install the debug versions of the apps you build.

Comment: Created a provisioning profile and got certificates. Not it displays error in build page. https://www.codenameone.com/build-server.html

Comment: I need the link to the error log not the generic server link

Comment: Fixed it. New error is "update process locked"
codename one update process in progress lock file exists at (C/user/path/Updatestatus.lock).
should i remove the .lock file? If i have to show a screenshot i might have to make another post

Comment: You can remove the lock file if it's old and irrelevant.